# When is capacity different from end of array - start of slice?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

In the [Go Programming Language](https://www.gopl.io/) book, the authors stated the following (at section 4.2 on slices):

> The length [of a slice] is the number of slice elements; it can't exceed the capacity, which is usually the number of elements between the start of the slice and the end of the underlying array.

#### Question

Since the authors chose to use the word "*usually*", it means that there would in fact be circumstances where the capacity of the slice is different from the number of elements between the start of the slice and the end of the underlying array---when would this be the case?

In other words, when will the expression below be `true`:

```golang
cap(mySlice) != len(underlyingArray) - startIndexOfSlice
```

The only case I can think of is when the slice is `nil`, in which case there will be no underlying array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full [slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) can set capacity short of the full underlying array.

```
x := make([]string, 20)
y := x[0:10:10]

fmt.Println("x:", len(x), cap(x)) // prints x: 20 20
fmt.Println("y:", len(y), cap(y)) // prints y: 10 10
```

The slices `x` and `y` share the same underlying array, but the capacity of `y` is less than the capacity of `x`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this variation of the slice expression. It is like the mirror operation of slicing `s[i:j]` where the low index is `i > 0` and the resultant slice forever loses reference to elements in the underlying array with index `< i`.